# A feeling that you missed something that you had to do(expression)

Tags: grammar, expressions

Let's say you got only an hour to finish your work. Then, that hour is now finished, but you **feel** that there is something you **didn't do.** Few minutes after that, you see that you have really missed a part of your work, and you say:

> ''So that explains why I **felt** that there **is** something I **didn't do** huh.''

Or is this more correct:

> ''So that explains why **I've been feeling** that there **is** something I **didn't do** huh.''

This is a common expression that will benefit ESLs also. Is there better/correct expression for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227950/a-word-to-describe-the-feeling-that-you-are-forgetting-something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So that explains why I felt that there is something I didn't do huh.

The verb tenses are not consistent: felt (past), is (present), didn't (past).

Here is one alternative: felt (past), was (past), hadn't (past perfect)

> So that explains why I felt like there was something which I hadn't done.

Next,

> So that explains why I've been feeling that there is something I didn't do huh.''

The tenses are: have been feeling (present perfect progressive tense), is (present), didn't (past).

The "present perfect progressive" is a bit complex to analyze grammatically in this context, but if that's the preferred tense then perhaps switching "didn't do" to "haven't done" yields a small improvement:

> So that explains why I've been feeling like there is something which I haven't done (yet).

---

Another [article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227950/a-word-to-describe-the-feeling-that-you-are-forgetting-something) mentions different ways to phrase it:

> Would a "nagging feeling" or "lingering doubt" suit your purpose?